# Error al compilar archivo python a exe (Auto-py-to-exe)

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

estoy intentando compilar un archivo .py que he programado desde tkinter. Soy bastante novato y estoy aprendiendo. Cualquier ayuda lo agradeceré.

¿alguien sabe porque da error al compilar el archivo .py a exe? Creo que tiene algo que ver con el modulo pygame que el archivo .py está cargando, pero no estoy seguro.

Tampoco entiendo en la ventana de la derecha (powershell), la linea que dice:

184 WARNING: Failed to collect submodules for 'setuptools._vendor.pyparsing.diagram' because importing 'setuptools._vendor.pyparsing.diagram' raised: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\marc3\Desktop\carpeta\env\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\pyparsing\diagram\template.jinja2'

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Con qué generaste el .exe?

Comment: Con auto-py-to-exe https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/

Comment: Prueba generando un .exe con pyinstaller con la condición de --onefile para tener todas las dependencias en un solo archivo.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vr9vl0qlggE&list=PLePBGIflFGil6M_kGLaJmVbyPxeH8zHwS&index=1&t=25s

Comment: Voy a probar, gracias!

Comment: Vale, ya lo he probado. Me genera el exe, pero este archivo python que intento compilar tiene dependencias. Es decir, no solo necesito compilar el archivo python sino también las imágenes y música. Y el problema, es que me genera el exe separado de los demás archivos y cuando ejecuto el exe no me carga el programa sino tiene los demás archivos en la misma carpeta.No se si me explico.     ¿Cómo podría empaquetarlo todo en un único exe?

Comment: Ayúdate con esta info: https://parzibyte.me/blog/2018/12/27/pyinstaller-assets-imagenes-archivos-ejecutable-python/

Comment: He leído el tutorial, pero me quedo en el paso 5 porque me arroja el siguiente mensaje: 142 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.3
142 INFO: Python: 3.7.0
142 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.22000-SP0
option(s) not allowed:
  --onedir/--onefile
makespec options not valid when a .spec file is given